# How to get php json data in c# using webAPI?

Tags: c#, php, json, asp.net-web-api

I use this php code to send my data as parameter

```
 $jsonData  = json_encode(array('shenase'=>$shenase,'fullname'=>$name,'nikokarhaghighi'=>$nikokarhaghighi,'nikokarhoghoghi'=>$nikokarhoghoghi,
'stateone'=>$stateone,'questionone'=>$questionone,'questiontwo'=>$questiontwo,
'statethree'=>$statethree,'stateFour'=>$stateFour,'statefive'=>$statefive));
```

I want to add this `$jsonData` at the end of my url like this

```
(...../check/checkdata?data=' . $jsonData).
```

I use webAPI to get this `$jsonData`. How can I  get this data in C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way you can do this. One is creating a model of data sent by your PHP code. i.e

```
class Model
{
public string shenase{get; set;}
public string fullname{get; set;}
// rest of the properties
}
```

In you C# WEB API

```
public HttpResponseMessage YourEndPoint([FromUri]Model model)
{
//this will atuomatically bind values sent in URL to model
}
```

Otherway is in you C# WebAPI instead of creating model just create corresponding parameters i.e.

```
public HttpResponseMessage YourEndPoint(string fullname, string shenase, ...)
{
//this will atuomatically bind values sent in URL to model
}
```

For detail please visit [WEB API model binding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).